# How do I prevent an error message when using get-process for a process that does not run?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

When I execute

```
get-process noSuchProcess
```

I get the error message

```
get-process : Cannot find a process with the name "noSuchProcess". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:5
+     get-process noSuchProcess
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (noSuchProcess:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Is it possible to prevent such an error message if a process does not exist?

Comment: get-process noSuchProcess -ErrorAction Ignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running:

```
get-process noSuchProcess 2>$null
```

will redirect stderr to null, so the error will not be printed.
See [powershell redirection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [Yosev Arbiv's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58948361/45375) with PowerShell-idiomatic alternatives, using the 
[`-ErrorAction` (`-ea`) common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6#erroraction):

```bash
# Ignores the error altogether.
# Note the use of the -ea alias for -ErrorAction
Get-Process noSuchProcess -ea Ignore

# Silences the error, but still records it in $Error (see next section)
Get-Process noSuchProcess -ea SilentlyContinue

# If you call an *external program*, you must use 2>$null to silence
# its stderr output.
whoami badarg 2>$null
```

Note:

- `-ErrorAction` (and `-ErrorVariable`, see below) can only be used with PowerShell cmdlets and advanced functions or scripts, not with external programs.
- To silence stderr output from external programs, use `2>$null`.

  - *Windows PowerShell*: `2>$null` is virtually equivalent to `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, except for the situationally different behavior introduced by the bug reported in [GitHub issue #4002](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002).
  - [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): `2>$null` is equivalent to `-ErrorAction Ignore`
- Both `-ErrorAction` and `2>` by default only act on *non-terminating* errors (the typical kind), not terminating ones, though, confusingly, the seemingly equivalent [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#erroractionpreference) acts on *all* errors.

  - For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling and its pitfalls, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

---

**Background information:**

<sup>Note: The term *cmdlets* below is used to refer not just to true (compiled) cmdlets, but also to their (written-in-PowerShell) counterparts, [advanced functions and scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced).</sup>

- PowerShell's analog to stderr (the standard error stream) is the *error [output] stream*, which is one of *6* available streams, documented in [about_Output_Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
- By default, all errors that occur in a session are recorded in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#error), in reverse chronological order (most recent one first) - whether they are printed to the console at the time they occur or not.

  - As an alternative to examining `$Error`, the [common `-ErrorVariable` (`-ev`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#errorvariable) allows you to capture a command's errors in a variable; e.g.:

    ```bash
        # Silence any errors, but capture them in variable $err
        Get-Process noSuchProcess -ea SilentlyContinue -ev err
    ```
  - There is no equivalent mechanism when you call external programs, though one has been proposed in [GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332).
- Using `-ErrorAction` in a cmdlet call:

  - `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` silences (doesn't print to the console) any error output, but still records it in `$Error`.
  - `-ErrorAction Ignore` both silences and suppresses addition to `$Error`
- Stderr output from *external programs* is *not* recorded in `$Error` by default (stderr output cannot generally assumed to represent *errors*, given that many programs, such as `git`, also use it to print *status* information).

  - [*Windows PowerShell* only, fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)] Somewhat paradoxically, using `2>$null` *does* cause the stderr lines to be recorded in `$Error`; this unexpected behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #11133](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11133).